# How do I include a .php or .html file in a .html file?

Tags: php, html, php-include

Say I have my file `index.html`, and I want to include `a.php` and `b.html` in them. How exactly will I go by doing this?

Here's what I got in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SQL DB Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>

<!--Changes -->

        <?php
            include 'a.php';
        ?>

    </body>


</html>
```

Here's my `a.php` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <p>
            Hello there, you rock.
        </p>
    </head>
</html>
```

And here's my `b.html` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <p>
            Hello there, you rock even more.
        </p>
    </head>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to get `index.html` to display its contents along with the contents of `a.php` and `b.html`? Currently, the little part with include `a.php` isn't working, so I thought I'd ask.

Thanks

Comment: You should make that a PHP file.

Comment: `<p>` is not valid in `<head>` and `<html>` is not flow content and therefore invalid in `<body>` so just include `<p>Hello, world<p>` not the rest.

Answer (score 4):

First thing: Change the extension of `index.html` to `index.php`. Otherwise the server isn't going to know there's PHP to be parsed.

Second, you don't need to repeat the `html`, `body`, `head` and other document tags that are already in the `index.php` file. With the includes, you're inserting data into that file, not creating new documents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SQL DB Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>

<!-- a.php file below -->

        <p>
            Hello there, you rock.
        </p>

<!-- b.php file below -->

        <p>
            Hello there, you rock even more.
        </p>

    </body>


</html>
```

Revised `a.php` file:

```
        <p>
            Hello there, you rock.
        </p>
```

Revised `b.php` file:

```
        <p>
            Hello there, you rock even more.
        </p>
```

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to me making it a .php file?

Comment: For all practical purposes, no. [Read more.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html+vs+php+file)

Comment: if supported and using Apache, they can instruct it to treat `.html` files as PHP. Plus, they can also (and if supported), use SSI with `.shtml` and include PHP files. I've done it often.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, agreed. But I'm trying to keep in simple, as it doesn't appear the OP must use `.html` or SSI. Switching to `.php` is simple, efficient and a good habit to get into, in my view.

Comment: OP here, right now I'm using brackets io, and when I switched index.html to index.php, stuff got weird. I couldn't do any live preview any more because of that unless I switched it back to index.html. Any tips?

Comment: @Michael_B FYI: OP reposted http://stackoverflow.com/q/34781037/ it's about brackets.io http://brackets.io/ and not [adobe-brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) and I closed that question.

Answer (score 0):

You have three solutions :

1. change the extension of `index.html` to `index.php`
2. OR you have to include `a.php` via `iframe`.
3. OR you have to call `a.php` via `ajax` and then put response where u want.